# Change Default Indentation in Android Studio & about the indentation terminology

Tags: android, ide, indentation

Instead of

```
for (...){
code;
}
```

I want:

```
for (...)
{
   code;
}
```

I want to change from the default style which is the first one, to the second style, in Android Studio. ALSO, could someone please tell me the terminology for each style? (if there is terminology for such things). Thanks!

Comment: yes it is a duplicate

Comment: What is the terminology?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 1):

In the newest Android IDE 1.2.1.1

You need to go to
File->Settings->Editor->Code Style->Java->Wrapping and Braces